# Grub error after removing another Linux partition with Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot

i have a problem, i had a dual boot system with windows 7 and ubuntu. I decided to try out linux mint. but after a while I removed it by deleting it´s partition.

When I restarted, the bootloader didn´t work anymore. I reinstalled linux mint so that I could use my pc again. but I really want to remove mint from my system. is there a way to delete mint and still be able to boot in to Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First Login in to Ubuntu and use this command in a terminal

   ```
   sudo grub-install /dev/sda
   ```
2. Then remove the Linux mint's partition using gparted or disk-utility.
3. Then use this command to update grub men

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

Now you should have a system with no Mint and no grub error!